# DllImport decorated name issue - Unable to find entry point

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dllimport

I have a weird problem I have C++ DLL that I am importing in C# library using DLL import. If I specify entry point, everything works as expected, here is the example:

```
internal static class UnsafeMethods
{
    [DllImport("GoodSchool.dll", EntryPoint = @"?AddNum@@YAHHH@Z")]
    public static extern int AddNum(int num1, int num2);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(UnsafeMethods.AddNum(4,5));
    }
}
```

However, if I use a simplfied import like here:

```
[DllImport("GoodSchool.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int AddNum(int num1, int num2);
```

I get familiar error message:

Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'AddNum' in DLL 'GoodSchool.dll'

I used depends to verify that method is properly exposed, and I decoded notation to verify parameters and naming convention - all seems good.

Function signature in C++ is very simple:

```
  __declspec(dllexport) int AddNum(int num1, int num2);
```

Any suggestions how I can call this method in C# without providing decorated name as EntryPoint? What do I do wrong?  I do not want to use "C" export, as my understanding is that decorated function name is perfectly fine to be used with DllImport.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason why you don't want to use the extern "C" declaration? "Because I think you don't have to" isn't really compelling.

Comment: I am using this DLL from C++ code, and there it works properly, so I would like to keep it the way it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ mangles function names to account for function name overloading.  After all, if the DLL had

```
__declspec(dllexport) int AddNum(int num1); 
__declspec(dllexport) int AddNum(int num1, int num2);
```

which would `AddNum` refer to?

The symbol `?AddNum@@YAHHH@Z` is the mangled (a.k.a. decorated) name exposed in the unmanaged DLL.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B

Your DLL does not export something called `AddNum`.

Comment: Yes, but i thought that since we provide a function declaration after attribute, there is enough information for compiler to reproduce the decorated name.

Comment: @SebastianK: Nope.  The mangled (decorated) name must be specified.  The DLL could have been produced by any number of different compilers.  The .NET runtime does not try and assume that the DLL was generated by Visual C++ (which would be a necessary first assumption if it wanted to unmangle the function name).

Comment: @SebastianK - P/Invoke doesn't involve the C# compiler - it is a CLR service.  In any case the C# compiler doesn't know how to do C++ name mangling and there is no standard for C++ name mangling.  Any compiler (or different version of the same compiler) can do mangling different.

Comment: Good point about CLR - I assumed mangling was standard process that CLR could reproduce based on call convention, parameters and return types. I guess I had that wrong.

Comment: @SebastianK: The CLR *could* theoretically recognize that the DLL contains mangled VC++ entry points and map those to C# symbols, but it chooses not to.  One reason for that choice may be that it would break anyhow if there were any function overloads.

Comment: @EricJ. link in wikipedia is dead you can replace with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B

Comment: Thanks for the updated link.  If you're sure of your change, it's generally fine just to edit in the new URL directly.

Answer (score 7):

The decorated function name is fine to use with `DllImport`, as you can see by the fact that you're doing it. But that requires you to *specify* the decorated function name in the import. The undecorated name does not exist as far as the linker (static or dynamic) is concerned -- `AddNum` is simply not a symbol that your library exposes.

If you instead want to do what you're asking:

> call this method in C# without providing decorated name as EntryPoint?

then you cannot allow C++ to mangle the name in the first place. You can *either* specify the decorated name in `DllImport` *or* use `extern "C"` linkage on the C++ code. You must pick one or the other.

Comment: Exactly - well stated. The compiler is not magical - it can't infer which unmanaged function you're trying to reference, if only because name-mangling isn't universal.

Comment: Ok, makes sense - I assumed mangling was more of a standard - that is depended on call convention, return type, and parameters only.